# event handlers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to build two functions:

```
var MyObject = new Object();
MyObject.MyProperty = 1;

function ListenToChange() {
  here I want to listen to changes in MyProperty1 and do something when it changes
}

function ThrowEvent () {
  here I change the value of MyProperty every 5 seconds
  setTimeOut('ThrowEvent', 5000);
}
```

I looked at the addEventListener property but it looks like it works for DOM objects. I thought of using the ThrowEvent function to change the value of a hidden div and listen for the changes in the value of the hidden with $('#HiddenDiv').change() but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it with the addEventListener.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How about using a setter function to alter myproperty and then firing ListenToChange from there? Although I am curious about the answer to this. +1 for a good question/

Comment: set properties in object by using set methods `setMyProperty(value)`, which would execute handling as well

Comment: @mrtsherman: how does this work in code?

Comment: I think I'll let this guy explain it - http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/ John Resig is known by a few more people than I am.

Comment: I'm wondering if [event delegation](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/02/19/javascript-event-delegation/) might help here.

Comment: Do you care about compatibility, or can you get away with targeting only certain engines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can infer from your example you're using jQuery; you could trigger a custom event anytime you change the value of your property:

```
var my_obj = {my_prop: 1}

function ListenToChange(event, newval) {
  console.log('my_prop is now' + newval)
}
$.bind("propchange:my_prop", ListenToChange)

function ThrowEvent () {
  $.trigger('propchange:my_prop', my_obj.my_prop)
  setTimeOut('ThrowEvent', 5000);
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the wrapper; I'm wrapping my head around the code. Can you add just a few comments in your code to show where the listening occurs and change the variable names to more meaningful name. I think your code looks fantastic.

Comment: I've removed the setter, it's complicated and you don't actually need it for your example. Just bind and trigger a custom event for when you're setting it.

Comment: Let's say in ThrowEvent I want to change the value to 11, I do this: $.trigger('propchange:my_prop', 11); ?

Comment: Well, without the setter you still need to set it, the event is just so you're notified of the change. `$.trigger('propchange:my_prop', my_obj.my_prop=11)` would do both.

Comment: ok, very clear; thank you so very much for your help. Happy Thanksgiving.

Answer (score 1):

Well here is an example of what I came up with. It is not nearly as glamorous as John's example, but it gets the job done. Recommendations for improvements are more than welcome.

http://jsfiddle.net/yKYRs/

```
var MyObject = new Object();

MyObject.MyProperty = 1;

MyObject.MyProperty_Set = function(val) {   
    this.MyProperty = val;   
    ListenToChange();
}

function ListenToChange() {
    console.log('My Property was changed');
}

MyObject.MyProperty_Set(2);
```

Comment: Ok, this looks really sweet and simple.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are after ES5 [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/set) and [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/get), however they won't work in an ECMAScript Ed 3 environment, you'll need to write your own getter and setter functions for that.

If you want to listen for changes to the DOM, there is a [W3C DOM 2 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/) specification that includes [mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents), however I don't think it was ever widely implemented. There is a [level 3 working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/) that deprecates a number of the level 2 features.